# Merge Excel columns by title

Tags: excel, join, excel-formula

I'm trying to transform this table (commas are cell-seperators):

```
X,Y,Z,Y,Z,Z,X 
a, , ,b, ,c,
 ,d,e, , , ,f
 , , ,g,h, ,i
```

Into this:

```
X,Y,Z
a,b,c
f,d,e
i,g,h
```

The problem is that the table is generated automatically (by a complicated blackbox) and I cannot expect what the header (the first row) will look like

The only thing I know for sure is that each distinct key (in the header) has exactly 1 value in all the cells matching that key in any given row (the rest are empty).
The order of the columns in the output table doesn't really matter.

I can do that with Python pretty easily, but would definitely prefer a pure-excel solution!

Can you help me?

Comment: *The only thing I know for sure is that each distinct key (in the header) has exactly 1 value in all the cells matching that key in any given row (the rest are empty)* Your example got values `b, g` in same column. Same for `f,i`. Notice you got 7 headers but 9 values...

Comment: do you want the result divided by commas, or is that to be read as a cell separator?

Comment: Is your `X,Y,Z,Y,Z,Z,X...` a table or is it really a table of strings? e.g. row 1 is `"X,Y,Z,Y,Z,Z,X"`, row 2 is `"a, , ,b, ,c,"`...

Comment: Although it really wasn't clear, comma is a cell separator and not part of a string :-)

Comment: The only thing I know for sure is that (when looking at any specific row) each distinct key (in the header) has exactly 1 value in all the cells matching that key *in any given row* (the rest are empty).

Answer (score 2):

I had this solution in Office 365, but I like Euler's version.

First get the headers :
`=UNIQUE(A1:G1,1)`

Then in the first cell under the first of the header use:
`=FILTER($A2:$G2,($A2:$G2<>"")*($A$1:$G$1=A$9))`

This second formula doesn't spill, so needs to be dragged.

If you have an older excel version you could use this formula in `I1`:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$G$1,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($H1:H1,$A$1:$G$1)=0,COLUMN($A$1:$G$1)),1)),"")` confirm the array-formula with `ctrl+shift+enter` and drage to the right.

in `J2` use:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$G$1,SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($H1:H1,$A$1:$G$1)=0,COLUMN($A$1:$G$1)),1)),"")` also to be confirmed with `ctrl+shift+enter` and to be dragged to the right and down.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully someone will come along with something better, but  this will work in the meantime if you have the newest version of Excel. First get the unique headers with something like  `=UNIQUE($A$1:$G$1,1)`, then `FILTER` the original dataframe by the header, join by column with `TEXTJOIN`, and finally separate with `FILTERXML`.

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(
TEXTJOIN(",", 1, FILTER($A$2:$G$4, $A$1:$G$1=A$10)),
 ",", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s")
```

[image]